# Finding integrer in tuple which is a key in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

The keys in the dictionary is made of different tuples with different integers, I need to print all values in the dictionary with that integer.

I have tried to get the values using dictionary.get() and dictionary.values()
in combination with different for loops.

```
#Vegetarian = 1
#Vegan = 2
#Gluten-free = 3
a = tuple([0])
# "Joe's Gourmet Burger"

b = tuple([1,3])
# "Main Street Pizza Company"

c = tuple([1,2,3])
# "Corner Cafe"

d = tuple([1])
# "Mama's Fine Italian"

e = tuple([1,2,3])
# "The Chef's Kitchen"

rest = {a:"Joe's Gourmet Burger",
        b:"Main Street Pizza Company",
        c:"Corner Cafe",
        d:"Mama's Fine Italian",
        e:"The Chef's Kitchen"}

food = set()
veg = input("does anyone need vegetarian? yes/no ")
if veg == "yes":
    food.add(1)

vegan = input("does anyone need vegan? yes/no ")
if vegan == "yes":
    food.add(2) 


glut =input("does anyone need gluten free? yes/no ")
if glut == "yes":
    food.add(3)

for num in food:
    print(num)
    print(rest[num])
```

This will give you the value of the chosen allergy.
What I had hoped for was the dictionary to recognize the keys in the tuples and then print out the corresponding restaurants. Further, if a user selects multiple allergies, the script should return only restaurants that satisfy all of the user's allergies.

what I get is "built-in method get of dict object at 0x000001ACC9DA4A68"

Comment: I don't see how the code sample can produce such output as "built-in method...". I would rather expect a KeyError.

Comment: By the way: c and e are equal and you can't have multiple items with equal key in a dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to print out the values if a user answers "yes" to any of the questions?

If so, this won't quite get you all the way there, but it should point you in the right direction:

```
for num in food:
    for k in rest.keys():
        if num in k:
            print(rest[k])
```

If I understand correctly, you need to check if a given number is present in each of the dictionary's keys (i.e. each tuple).

To @Michael Butscher 's point, this won't be quite useful as you will have duplicate keys. Instead, you could restructure your data structure to something that has a list of restaurants for each key:

```
requirements = {
    0: "None",
    1: "Vegetarian",
    2: "Vegan",
    3: "Gluten-free"
}
requirement_restaurant_map = {
    0: ["Joe's Gourmet Burger"],
    1: ["Main Street Pizza Company", "Corner Cafe", "Mama's Fine Italian", "The Chef's Kitchen"],
    2: ["Corner Cafe", "The Chef's Kitchen"],
    3: ["Main Street Pizza Company", "Corner Cafe", "The Chef's Kitchen"]
}

food = set()
veg = input("does anyone need vegetarian? yes/no ")
if veg == "yes":
    food.add(1)

vegan = input("does anyone need vegan? yes/no ")
if vegan == "yes":
    food.add(2) 

glut = input("does anyone need gluten free? yes/no ")
if glut == "yes":
    food.add(3)

intersection = []
for num in food:
    for k in requirements:
        if num == k:
            if not intersection:
                intersection.extend(requirement_restaurant_map[k])
        else:
            intersection = list(set(intersection).intersection(set(requirement_restaurant_map[k])))

print(f"The following restaurants satisfy your requirements...\n {intersection}")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I tought about doing that, but the problem occurs when someone need a place that is both 1 and 3 because that would print out duplicates, I was thinking if it would be possible to do a set.union solution but I cannot fanthom how that would work.

Comment: I edited the second code snippet of my answer to include restaurants that satisfy multiple constraints. This is done by using `set`'s `intersection` method

Comment: I see! thank you very much for taking your time to answer, now atleast I am aware of what I need to look into next.